# Perl to Python script hashing

Tags: python-2.7, perl, hash

```
if ( ! exists $tRHash{$tR} ) {

    if ( $start < $end ) {

        $pS = $start - 41;
        $pE = $end + 40;
        print "$chr\t$pS\t$pE\tpre-$tR\t0\t$st\n";
    }
    else {

        $pS = $end - 40;
        $pE = $start + 40;
        print "$chr\t$pS\t$pE\tpre-$tR\t0\t$st\n";
    }

    $tRHash{$tR} = $tR;
}
```

How can I do this in Python, especially the hashing part? I have executed the `if` statement but I am struggling with the output format as in Perl.

```python
pS, pE = zip(*[(n - 41, m + 40) if n < m else (n + 40, m - 40)
           for n, m in zip(start, end)])
```

Comment: The Python you show works differently from the Perl code. Why use fancy list comprehension when a simple `if` `else` like in Perl will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the `print` statement then this should help

I can't tell what sort of data your variables hold, so I've assumed that `chr` is one-character string and everything else is an integer

```python
chr = 'A'
pS = 100
pE = 208
tR = 10
st = 20

print "%s\t%d\t%d\tpre-%d\t0\t%d\n" % (chr, pS, pE, tR, st);
```

#### output

```
A   100 208 pre-10  0   20
```

Comment: What placeholder should be used if data is alphanumeric like Abc-47-1

Comment: @KR12: That's a string of characters, so use `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

I also looking for it from a very long time, Now I completed Python training and here is my understanding.

Please use the **Dictionary** **data type** in python, its very very **simile** to the **hash**... Its also supported nested, simile to the to nested hash.

Only point is you needs to search for **Dictionary** in python instead of **Hash** in Perl.

Hope this Example will help you understand:-

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
dict['Age'] = 8; # update existing entry
dict['School'] = "DPS School" # Add new entry

print ("dict['Age']: ", dict['Age'])
print ("dict['School']: ", dict['School'])
```

> Dictionary data type:- 
>   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm

Hopes its solves the problem..